# Using a for loop while maintaining list object

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a complete beginner trying to learn lists and for loops. In this example I have a list called "December". The values represent the temperatures for the first three days in December. The user can specify a day and receive the temperature. Right now the code is very repetitive. I would like to know how to make the code efficient using a loop. But I'd rather not turn the list into a dictionary if it can be avoided.

```
    December = [5, 10, 12]

    day = int(raw_input('Search day in December: '))
    if day == 1:
       print "The temperature ", day, "December was:", December[0], "celsius"
    elif day == 2:
       print "The temperature ", day, "December was:", December[1], "celsius"
    elif day == 3:
       print "The temperature ", day, "December was:", December[2], "celsius"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if day == 1:
   print "The temperature ", day, "December was:", December[0], "celsius"
elif day == 2:
   print "The temperature ", day, "December was:", December[1], "celsius"
elif day == 3:
   print "The temperature ", day, "December was:", December[2], "celsius"
```

Becomes:

```
print "The temperature ", day, "December was:", December[day - 1], "celsius"
```

This also works for `day > 3`

Comment: I don't get it. My problem is that I repeat elif statements. That's going to get tedious considering there's 31 days in December. I' afraid I can't see how your line is going to change that.

Comment: @VillaRava I mean using my line _instead_ of the `elif` statements

Comment: I tried that. That way the user can only type "1" to get a temperature. Typing "2" or "3" does nothing.

Comment: @VillaRava remove the `if` too

Comment: Wow! I'm perplexed how easy that was. No loop needed.

Comment: @VillaRava If it worked for you, you can signify gratitude by clicking the ckeckmark near the arrows.

Comment: Sure! Now I'm thinking it would be a good idea to notify the user if the input is not in the range of December (for instance typing "4"). Is there an equally plain way to do this without using an if-else block?